# why does the second square disappear

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Why does the second square disappear when I press a arrow key? 
And instead of disappearing the second square is supposed to be following the first square. I checked every line of code and none have anything wrong and the browser I am using is Google Chrome.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
     <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var win = false;
    var player = {
        x:250,
        y:250,
        speed:5,
        width:100,
        height:100
    };
    var ai = {
        x:150,
        y:150,
        mox:0,
        moy:0,
        speed:1,
        width:50,
        height:50
    };
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillRect(ai.x, ai.y, ai.width, ai.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    function a() {
        if(player.x < ai.x && win==false) {
            ai.mox-=ai.speed;
        }
        if(player.x > ai.x && win==false) {
            ai.mox = ai.speed;
        }
        if(player.y < ai.y && win==false) {
            ai.moy -= ai.speed;
        }
        if(player.y > ai.y && win==false) {
            ai.moy = ai.speed;
        }
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillRect(ai.x, ai.y, ai.width, ai.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
function move(e) {
    // alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode==37) {
        player.x -= player.speed;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==39) {
        player.x += player.speed;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==38) {
        player.y -= player.speed;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==40) {
        player.y+=player.speed;
    }
    ai.x += ai.mox;
    ai.y += ai.moy;
    a();
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.stroke();
}
document.onkeydown = move;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code. Also a syntax checker told me it is syntactically correct.

Comment: Please format your code, so it's actually human readable. Then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's some problems with this, I'll get to those later.
To immediately fix your issue, you need to add

`ctx.fillRect(ai.x, ai.y, ai.width, ai.height);`

Immediately after

`ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);`

---

Okay, back to the problems. Most HTML5 canvas games have a tick function that's called every x MS, you don't seem to have this at all. There's a few other minor issues with the code but I think you'll be able to figure out those as you learn more. Best of luck :)